# TinyMCE is removing plus sign from my content once saved

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce

I am using extended valid elements and plus sign still disappears even if I add hex/html version..

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3aextended_valid_elements

Does anyone have a solution

Comment: Perhaps you could make a TinyMCE Fiddle that shows what is happening?  Without any code or an example there is very little people can do to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was not really with tinyMCE, but with the Ajax post/save method..
Once the content was sent to other php + signs were replaced with a blank space..

I have solved the problem with encodeURIComponent(contentvariable) as a dataString.